# In Vue, how do I listen to an input change event?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue, how do I execute a method when a change to my input field has occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a native attribute lister like `@input='runMyMethod'` or use a `watcher` to check when your data binding changes.

A `watcher`is recommended if you're binding to a `data` property and not a `prop`.

Read more about `watchers` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@change="myMethod"` or use `Watcher`.

On `Vue` Documentation you can read about `Computed and Watcher Properties`.

I always prefer `watcher`